# How to check whether file is exists or not in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have these code to post the data from a.php into b.php

From a.php, I use ajax post and b.php will do the processing.

But in b.php, I want to make sure the files is not duplicate before the data is insert into database.

I try to use the basic coding to check but why the code is not working ?

Here's my current code.

**a.html**

```
<form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p>Select File 
        <input type="file" id="multiFiles" name="upload_file[]" multiple accept="file/*" /> 
    </p>  
    <input type="submit" id="upload_button" name="upload_button" class="btn btn-info"  value="Upload" />
</form>
```

below HTML code I use jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#pick').click(function(){

            var multiFilesInput = document.getElementById('multiFiles');
            var filesmsg = multiFilesInput.files;

            for(var i = 0; i<filesmsg.length; i++) 
            { 
                var filename        = filesmsg[i].name;   

                $.post( "b.php", 
                {  
                    file_name       : filename 
                })
                .done(function( data ) { 

                });

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

**b.php**

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php'; 
    $filename = '/rootfolder/'.$_POST['file_name'].'';
    if(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename))
    {
        // Insert the data into database
    }
    else
    {
        // Ignore. Data not added
    }
```

Please help me. Am I missing something here ? The code always execute on insert to db even the files already exists in the folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename` is giving correct path? check and let us know a sample path what it produced.

Comment: I already try to put dummy path and paste it into url browser and its working fine. I'm so confuse right now why the code not working.

Comment: Did you do what Alive To Die suggested? What was the result? It's not clear, from your comment

Comment: do `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename);` before `if(!file_exists(....)){` and let us know what path is coming

Comment: What I mean is I tried to put $filename = 'rootfolder/test_file.pdf'; . but the if statement always go to !file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename) even in folder already contain the file.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` doesn't normally have the trailing `/` so `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$filename` could well end up being something like `/var/www/httpdocsindex.html` which is obviously going to fall over...

Comment: var_dump shows 'opt/lampp/htdocs/rootfolder/test123.pdf' . Somehow it cannot read the files inside the directory . I wonder why

Comment: turns out I need to add ../ because the folder is located inside other sub folder in root. Thanks for your help .God bless you all :D